# I need to create a post in the webpage without refreshing the page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my webpage, the user can write a post and the data the user enters is then stored in the database. I want that data to be Selected by  a query and posted into the webpage but without the page being reloaded.

I am aware that I need to use Ajax, but I do not know how to use it. I need the post to be added to the page when the post button available in the webpage is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not know how to use it, why not try to [read up](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) on it? :)

To give you a gist of what you need to do, the button needs to be tied to an event handler in Javascript/JQuery. That event handler will be responsible for making the AJAX call and retrieving the information from the server. The call would be something like:

```
$.ajax({type: 'GET', url: '/path/to/information'})
```

Calling `.done()` on this particular AJAX call will execute the callback function specified in the parameter. Usually it's done like so:

```
$.ajax(...).done(function(data) { ... });
```

Where `data` is the response data on a **successful** (200) response. Once you receive the data, you would just use Javascript to update the html/text of an element on the DOM. How you implement this is solely up to you, but I suggest reading up and trying to get it to work before asking!